# Java - Finding all possible forms of a word with vowels swapped

Tags: java, recursion, permutation, backtracking

Given a word that contains vowels, I am trying to write a method that will discover all possible permutations of this word created by swapping out its vowels.

For instance if the word is "root" the resulting Set would look similar to:

```
{"roat", "roet", "roit", "rout", "royt", "reet", "riot", "reat" ...}
```

My initial strategy was to treat this like a recursive backtracking problem and I've written the following method:

```
public static final String VOWELS = "aeiouy";

    ...

    vowelSwap(emptySet, listRepresentingString, 0); // the initial recursive call

private void vowelSwap(Set<String> swaps, List<Character> list, int start) {
        for (int i = start; i < list.size(); i++) {
        if (isVowel(list.get(i))) {
            // do some vowel swapping on this character
            for (int j = 0; j < VOWELS.length(); j++) {
                if (list.get(i) != VOWELS.charAt(j)) {
                    char temp = list.get(i);
                    list.set(i, VOWELS.charAt(j));
                    String s = stringify(list);
                    swaps.add(s);
                    vowelSwap(swaps, list, i + 1);
                    list.set(i, temp);
                }
            }
        }
}

public static String stringify(List<Character> list) {
    ...
    a method that converts a List<Character> to String
}
```

which works, but experiences awful runtimes when you have large numbers of vowels in a word. (Given n vowels in a word, there are 6^n variations I believe?)

My question is this:

**How could I approach this problem in a way that will give me faster results in the case of words with many vowels?**

Edit: 6^n variations, not n^6

Comment: runtime shouldn't be that bad, I mean for `n=10`, there is only 1 million variations, thats a blink

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The 6^n value gives you the complexity of the problem (also, there is the time needed to iterate through each letter in the original word to check if it is a vower or consonant, but that is supposed to be too small in comparation). There is no sane way to change that, what you are doing is in fact, counting from 0 to (6^n) - 1, in base 6.

Anyway your code is not doing that, it just replaces one of the vowels each time and does not explore all the possibilities, leaving the values to n*6. As you leave the last vowel in place, you will be getting, from "root"

```
raot, reot, riot, root, ruot, ryot, ryat, ryet ....
```

My take would be

1) Add the empty String "" to the list of results

2) If letter is a consonant, add it behind all of the strings in the list. Delete previous values (String is invariant so you cannot just modify the object in the list, you must delete it and add the new variation).

3) If letter is a vowel, get all the strings in the list and put each of the vowels, in turn. Add all of these results to the List (and delete the previous ones). You will get 6x[previous number of strings]

4) Repeat

Comment: fixed in the question too, @SJuan76 could you clarify for me how I'm not exploring all possibilities with this solution? I was thinking that the list.set(i, temp) call was doing the "unchoosing" after each recursive call

Comment: I didn't notice that you reset the vowel value, anyway still you are not finding all of the combinations (you would get "raot, reot, riot, root, ruot, ryot, roat, roet....")